# Hyperledger Indy] How does indy know alice's name at the very first?

Tags: hyperledger-indy

I'm trying to know deeper about hyperledger indy so I tried the tutorials provided by https://try.connect.me/.

The first session is to get Faber college's transcripts. I've never registered or give a bit of Alice's personal information, however Faber college returned accurate Alice's transcription which is already including Alice's name.

Now, my question is if I build a new mobile app using indy, when is the right time I should get the personal information such as users' name from app users?

Answer (score 0):

I think the name is just hardcoded or automatically assigned to the connection just for simplicity of the tutorial.

There should be a middle step where Faber asks for proof who has sent the request for connection. You can check [the video with demonstration](https://github.com/hyperledger/education/blob/master/LFS171x/indy-material/nodejs/demo/SpencerHolman_2018-06-14_IndyAgentDemo.mp4) which shows Faber asks for proof of user's name via proof request after connection has been established between two identities.

Up until requesting a connection, the connection is just pairwise of DIDs for creating secure communication and the Faber doesn't know or more precisely cannot be sure if the requester is Alice who graduated at Faber University.

So in reality before Faber requests for proof that Alice is actually Alice (any personal information Alice owns), she should have already received a digital credential of her personal ID provided and issued by eg. Government (as it is in the demo video mentioned above). Once she owns the credential she can create proof of her name (and another personal data she is requested to prove) requested by Faber so Faber will know Alice is Alice.

I think this step is missing in the example just for simplicity.